# RTL languages support in DHTMLX or EXTJS4

Tags: user-interface, extjs, openlayers, dhtmlx

I develop map web application that use openlayers.In this application i want to use DHTMLX or Extjs4 for application front end.My application language layout is RTL.
which of DHTMLX or EXTJS4 supports RTL?
I see in some blogs that said that DHTMLX RTL support is include only in pro version,But i want to use GPL version of DHTMLX.Can i use rtl support in GPL version of DHTMLX?
I can't see any support of RTL in ExtJs4.1.They support RTL in ExtJs4.2 my question about Extjs4.1 is that can i use RTL in some widget of ExtJs4.1 like tree panle and some other widgets?

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS just expects JSON data from the backend. So if your RTL can send json to the treegrids or the normal grids you should be fine to use ExtJS.